# Hibernate noob: criteria to fetch not mapped relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have two classes in a many-to-many relationship, but only one of them have a list to the other.

```
@Entity
public class Product{
  @ManyToMany
  List<Category> categories;
  //...
}

@Entity
public class Category{
  //...
}
```

I want to find all Products related to a Category using Criteria, but the following doesn't work.

```
import static java.util.Collections.singletonList;

List<Product> getProductsByCategory(Category category){
    List<Product> results = getCurrentSession()
                            .createCriteria(Product.class)
                            .add(Restrictions.in("categories", singletonList(category)))
                            .list();
    if (results == null || results.size() <= 0)
        throw new EntityNotFoundException(category + "is empty");
    return results;
}
```

Of course that would be really simple if Product was mapped to Category, but surely Hibernate let's you do such a query without it.

EDIT:

It returns an Oracle error

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you get any error or it just didn't return the expected result? If error, what error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Product.class, "product");
c.createAlias("product.categories", "category");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("category.id", category.getId());
List<Product> results = c.list();
```

Note: the result list will NEVER be null. And its size will NEVER be < 0. An empty list is the right thing to return if the category doesn't have any product. I wouldn't throw an exception in this case.

Comment: I didn't do my homework and completely ignored createAlias(). Thanks so much!

About the test, it came from the example in a book (_Spring Persistence with Hibernate_), but I felt awkward using it... good to know the query never returns weird stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Product> results = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Product.class)
                        .createCriteria("categories")
                            .add(Restrictions.in("id", uniqueIds(categories)))
                        .list();
```